# Why laravel hosted at Heroku randomly throws (Random symbols*) method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

My laravel website works fine locally, but when deployed at heroku, it sometimes thows error when submitting:

```
The H.VIVASTREET.CO.UK%2FCARS%2FGBGET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.
```

My form is very simple,

```
 <form method="post" action="{{route('cars.store')}}">
    @csrf
    <input name="link" type="text" id="link" value="https://search.vivastreet.co.uk/cars/gb"/>
    <button type="submit">Download content</button>
 </form>
```

I have declared method `post`, why error says that method is `H.VIVASTREET.CO.UK%2FCARS%2FGBGET`
How to fix it?

Comment: What is the route defined for `cars.store`? It's trying to access `H.VIVASTREET.CO.UK/CARS/GBGET`

Comment: `Route::resource('cars', 'CarController')->only(['index', 'store']);` why is it tryingto acces it?

Comment: That's a very good question. Look at the source in the browser to see what the action is set to.

Comment: it is set to `http://obscure-journey-81618.herokuapp.com/cars` it also gives error in console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

Comment: Interesting. Check for redirects in middleware or htaccess or any javascript manipulation, and double-check the other 405 in the Network tab. It may have a similar issue.

Comment: It works now, it happens randomly, I guess it's heroku, because my app works perfectly locally